# How to validate login credentials in symfony (server side) for length, text etc?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Symfony 2.4.4, default login mechanism that comes with it.
I am able to validate the username & password from DB by linking the entities, but i would also like to validate my username and password for length etc... 
Any suggestions?

Comment: I only get "Bad credentials" message. I want to say "email invalid", "you left your password blank" etc

Comment: How do you build your login form? Via direct `HTML`: adding '_username', '_password' fields to your template or via `Symfony` `Form`?

Comment: I am using symfony's own login form